# Panning issues with theSaffire pro 56 and PT 10

Tags: pro-tools-10

I cannot hear the panning in any of my sessions. I am running a Mac Pro, 16 gigs of ram, Saffire Pro 56, and Pt 10. When I test in pro tools, I can see the tracks that i pan hard left and right are hitting the master fader properly, but In my monitors there is no difference. Everything plays back through both speakers even when I pan hard left and right. Please help,
Thanks,
Luke

Comment: Does your Saffire have any hardware (or software) mixing options? Is there a chance that there's some funny routing going on there? Do any other applications exhibit the same problem?

Comment: Some pictures of the specifics would help.